# How to get closed form solution of transcendental equation?

Tags: equation-solving

*Transcendental-Equation (closed form solution)*

- I want some method to get closed form solution of a transcendental equation and that is in terms of Lambert's Omega function.
- The equation $x + e^x = k$ has a closed form solution $x = W(k)$, but what about equation in some other form like $x + \sin (x) = k$?
  Please reply...
  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a good question.

Comment: We generally prefer to answer questions where you’ve tried yourself to get a solution with the software Mathematica, but can’t get your code to work....at the current stand this is a question for math.stackexchange.com ...did you  intend to ask there?

Comment: In general, one does ***not*** expect closed form solutions for transcendental equations. In the case of $x+\exp(x)=k$ and similar equations, the Lambert function (and the related Wright function) had to be created just to represent their solutions, but it is not always applicable.

Answer (score 4):

There are no known closed form analytic solution. However, one can obtain a series solution.

```
s=InverseSeries[Series[x+Sin[x],{x,0,3}],k]
r[k_]=N[Normal[InverseSeries[Series[x+Sin[x],{x,0,20}],k]]]
```

It yields

```
(* k/2+k^3/96+O[k]^5 *)
(* 0.5 k+0.0104167 k^3+0.000520833 k^5+0.0000333271 k^7+2.4005*10^-6 k^9+1.85392*10^-7 k^11+1.49923*10^-8 k^13+1.25265*10^-9 k^15+1.07246*10^-10 k^17+9.35709*10^-12 k^19 *)
```

A few values are

```
 Table[r[k],{k,0,3}]
```

> {0.,0.510973,1.10606,2.12739}

Answer (score 3):

I do not see how `x+ sin (x) = k` this can be solved in closed form. But only for specific value of `k` and Mathematica can solve it, but gives numerical values.

```
 Plot[x + Sin[x], {x, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
  InputForm@Table[x /. First@Solve[x + Sin[x] == k, x, Reals], {k, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 N[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You could obtain values of `k` as function of `x` which satisfies the equation (around $x=0$ using

```
  sol = AsymptoticSolve[x + Sin[x] == k, {k}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Around $x=1$

```
  sol = AsymptoticSolve[x + Sin[x] == k, {k}, {x, 1, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And so on. It does not seem that there is  closed form solution for any constant $k$. But you could ask in the math group. May be there is some magic someone there can come up with.